# Application with document for download - How?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-4.5

I have WPF application in which I would like users to download a specific file that will be included within the application.

Within my **.csproj** file, I have a **Files** folder with the pertinent file, say **Benefits.docx** and in **Visual Studios' Properties** window, I have set the `Build Action = Content` and `Copy Always` setting as well.

In my XAML, I have a button for the user to download the file locally:

```
<Button>
 <Hyperlink NavigateUri="/Files/Benefits.docx">Download</Hyperlink>
</Button>
```

What else am I missing since nothing happens?  Looking at the **/bin** folder, I can see that **/Files/Benefits.docx** is there.

Comment: Beside download link, you can copy and paste that file to a particular folder. May be Download folder?

Comment: @iJay - Thanks for your reply, but how does renaming and/or creating another folder assist with the file being actually rendered/copied?  The issue is not file location or the folder, but rather I need to be able to "get" the file from wherever the application is installed on the user's PC.

Comment: So First, you need to copy that file when you install the application on user's computer. Isn't it?

Comment: @iJay - The file is automatically part of the deployment.  From my initial question, I have the Excel file set to Build Action = Content.  This means that the file is copied into the bin.  Does this help?

Comment: Yes, but what do you want to do exactly? Copy that Docx file to a some location or open that file? What do you mean by downloading?

Comment: @iJay When OP said "download", she actually meant "load" (in an external application).

Comment: @Clemens Well you read her mind faster than me ! ;) Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you do not actually want to download a file, but just open an external application (like Word) to show a document that is part of your application.

You could do this by either a Button or a Hyperlink, but not both at the same time.

Using a Hyperlink would look like this:

```
<TextBlock>
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="Files/Benefits.docx"
               RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">Open</Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

Note that there is no leading `/` in the NavigateUri, which makes it a relative file name.

The `RequestNavigate` event handler would look like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
...

private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    var path = Path.GetFullPath(e.Uri.ToString());
    Process.Start(path);
}
```

---

Using a Button instead of a Hyperlink might look like shown below, where the reletive file path is set to the Button's `Tag` property, to be available in the Click event handler.

```
<Button Content="Open" Click="Button_Click" Tag="Files/Test.docx"/>
```

The Click event handler:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var file = (string)button.Tag;
    var path = Path.GetFullPath(file);
    Process.Start(path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've implemented your code but am running into something that should be relatively trivial. An exception is being thrown because it thinks path = "C:\\Files\\Benefits.docx" and when I look at the Debugger, I notice that all of the other properties for e.Uri are not filled except for e.Uri.OriginalString, which is "/Files/Benefits.docx".  I hate to ask since the answer should be obvious, but would you happen to know how to gather the relatively executing path?

Comment: I just noticed your latest reply, I am currently implementing and will report back shortly, thanks!

Comment: It's in the answer: "there is no leading `/` in the NavigateUri". That makes it a relative file name.

Comment: Your Button_Click() is clever with the Tag and it works!